# Under what condition, $n(>2)$ non-zero vectors of equal length forms a regular n-gon in Euclidean plane

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, functional-analysis

Suppose we have a unit circle in $R^{2}$ and $f_{1}, f_{2}, \cdots ,f_{n}$ be n vectors s.t. $\|f_{i}\|=1~\forall~i=1,2,\ldots,n$.\
Also we assume that $f_{1}=(1,0)$.\
Under what condition the vectors will form a regular n-gon ?\
At least try to give some hints when $n=3,4$ or $5$.

Answer (score 1):

You can take $\mathbb{R}^2$ as 1-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{C}$, then $f_1=1$ and $f_k=e^{\frac{i\pi}{n}(k-1)}$.